# Texture lookup inside FBO simulation shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fbo

I'm trying to make FBO-particle system by calculating positions in separate pass. 
Using code from this post now http://barradeau.com/blog/?p=621.
I render sphere of particles, without any movement:

[image]

The only thing i'm adding so far is a texture in **simulation** fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    vec3 pos = texture2D( texture, vUv ).xyz;
    //THIS LINE, pos is approx in -200..200 range
    float map = texture2D(texture1, abs(pos.xy/200.)).r;
    ...
    // save map value in ping-pong texture as alpha
    gl_FragColor = vec4( pos, map );
```

`texture1` is:  half black half white.

Then in **render** vertex shader i read this map parameter:

```
map = texture2D( positions, position.xy ).a;
```

and use it in **render** fragment shader to see the color:

```
vec3 finalColor = mix(vec3(1.,0.,0.),vec3(0.,1.,0.),map);
gl_FragColor = vec4( finalColor, .2 );
```

So what i hope to see is: (made by setting same texture in **render** shaders)

[image]

But what i really see is: (by setting texture in **simulation** shaders)

[image]

Colors are mixed up, though mostly you can see more red ones where they should be, but there are a lot of green particles in between.
Also tried to make my own demo with simplified texture and same idea and i got this:

[image]

Also mixed up, but you can still guess image.
Same error.
I think i am missing something obvious. But i was struggling with this a couple of days now, not able to find a mistake by myself.

Would be very grateful for someone to point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Demo with error: http://cssing.org.ua/examples/fbo-error/
Full code i'm referring: https://github.com/akella/fbo-test

Comment: Have you tried disabling texture filtering by using `GL_NEAREST`?

Comment: Well, it worked! i will confirm that later tonight, but so far made a commit to https://github.com/akella/fbo-test with how i understand what you mean, and worked out well! Will have a question to myself why it works by default in render pass, but not like that in simulation. But i officially owe you a beer if i confirm that tonight!

Comment: Confirmed! That was the problem. Could you add this to your answer so i can mark it as the correct one? Works now! http://cssing.org.ua/examples/fbo-particles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable texture filtering by using `GL_NEAREST` min/mag filters.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `THREE.TextureLoader()` loads texture with mipmaps and `texture2D` call in vertex shader uses the lowest-res mipmap. In vertex shaders you should use `texture2DLod(texture, texCoord, 0.0)` - note the 3rd param, `lod`, which specifies 0 mipmap level.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! But i actually load texture in **fragment** shader in simulation. =( I tried `map = texture2DLod(texture1, abs(vec2(pos.x/100.,pos.x/100.)), 0.0);` but it didnt change this blur bug.

Comment: Ouch, it was cache, texture2DLod does work only in vertex shader as far as i understand, right? But i do lookup in fragment.

Comment: Yes, `texture2DLod` is available only in vertex shaders. You can refer to this official GLSL cheat sheet from Khronos group - https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf - it comes really handy.